# How to best return a double from a PQueue of integers?

Tags: java, types

I add ints to minHeap and maxHeap (to keep track of current stream of numbers so I can find the median easily), compare them as Integer when the PQueue heapifies and keep them in the PQueues as integers. However, I need to divide them and return a double and don't return as precise enough of a result when I divide integer by integer. I can't cast Integer to a Double. What is the best approach here?

```
   public class MedianFinder {

        class MaxHeapComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
            public int compare(Integer x, Integer y) {
                return y-x;
            }
        }

        PriorityQueue minHeap = new PriorityQueue(5); // all elements greater than current median
        PriorityQueue maxHeap = new PriorityQueue(5, new MaxHeapComparator()); // all elements less than current median

        // Adds a number into the data structure.
        public void addNum(int num) {
            if (minHeap.size() == maxHeap.size()) { // handles case for both heaps being empty
                maxHeap.add(num);
            } else if (minHeap.size() < maxHeap.size()) {
                if (num < findMedian()) {
                    minHeap.add(maxHeap.poll());
                    maxHeap.add(num);
                } else {
                    minHeap.add(num);
                }
            } else if (minHeap.size() > maxHeap.size()) {
                if (num < findMedian()) {
                    maxHeap.add(num);
                } else {
                    maxHeap.add(minHeap.poll());
                    minHeap.add(num);
                }
            }
        }

        // Returns the median of current data stream
        public double findMedian() {
            if (minHeap.size() == 0 && maxHeap.size() == 0) {
                return 0;
            } else if (minHeap.size() == maxHeap.size()) {
                return ((double)minHeap.peek() + (double)maxHeap.peek()) / 2;
            } else if (minHeap.size() < maxHeap.size()) {
                return (double)maxHeap.peek();
            } else if (minHeap.size() > maxHeap.size()) {
                return (double)minHeap.peek();
            }
            return 0;
        }
    };

    // Your MedianFinder object will be instantiated and called as such:
    // MedianFinder mf = new MedianFinder();
    // mf.addNum(1);
    // mf.findMedian();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Integer` class extends `Number`, which has a method `doubleValue()`.  This returns a `double`, so you can just call it before your division.